# How can I show a popup of an image at the location the button was clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that fills the entire screen. What I want to do is:
Find the location of where the button was tapped and then make an image appear at that location in swift. I'm having trouble determining where the `UIButton` was tapped. I've searched everywhere and have found nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, it looks like you *don't* want to use a `UIButton`, but, rather, a normal `UIView` with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: And how may I do that?

Comment: What did you try so far?